# jQuery ajax function in success function gets disregarded if page redirect is present

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request where I would like some jQuery animation to finish before I reload the page. The problem is that my animation function "flyToChart" gets totally disregarded and the page reloads immediately. If I comment out the reload page code, the animation works perfectly. How can I make my animation run first and afterwards reload the page or even redirect to another page? Here is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'session/phpSession.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                ProductDescription: productDescription,
                ProductPrize: productPrize,
                ProductSize: productSize,
                ProductId: productId,
                ProductCount: productListJson.length,
                ProductSmallImage: productSmallImg,
                ProductQuantity: productQuantity,
                ProductUniqueId: idGen.getId(),
                ProdId: prodId,
            },

            success: function() {
                flyToCart(reload);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus + " " + xhr + " " + errorThrown );
            }
        });

function flyToCart(reload) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop' : $(".cart_anchor").position().top
    });

    var itemImg = $('.productBigImageContainer').find('img');
    flyToElement($(itemImg), $('.cart_anchor'));

    reload();
}

function flyToElement(flyer, flyingTo) {
    var $func = $(this);
    var divider = 3;
    var flyerClone = $(flyer).clone();
    $(flyerClone).css({position: 'absolute', top: $(flyer).offset().top + "px", left: $(flyer).offset().left + "px", opacity: 1, 'z-index': 1000});
    $('body').append($(flyerClone));
    var gotoX = $(flyingTo).offset().left + ($(flyingTo).width() / 2) - ($(flyer).width()/divider)/2;
    var gotoY = $(flyingTo).offset().top + ($(flyingTo).height() / 2) - ($(flyer).height()/divider)/2;

    $(flyerClone).animate({
        opacity: 0.4,
        left: gotoX,
        top: gotoY,
        width: $(flyer).width()/divider,
        height: $(flyer).height()/divider
    }, 700,
    function () {
        $(flyingTo).fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(flyingTo).fadeIn('fast', function () {
                $(flyerClone).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(flyerClone).remove();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

function reload()
{
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: You need to put the redirect in the callback of your animation function.

Comment: you need to put reload function inside flyToCart function

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for the comment, I added a callback function, but it did not change anything. I have edited my question with the callback function. I am not sure if the callback is implemented correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below code ::

```js
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'session/phpSession.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                ProductDescription: productDescription,
                ProductPrize: productPrize,
                ProductSize: productSize,
                ProductId: productId,
                ProductCount: productListJson.length,
                ProductSmallImage: productSmallImg,
                ProductQuantity: productQuantity,
                ProductUniqueId: idGen.getId(),
                ProdId: prodId,
            },

            success: function() {
                flyToCart();               
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus + " " + xhr + " " + errorThrown );
            }
        });

function flyToCart() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop' : $(".cart_anchor").position().top
    });

    var itemImg = $('.productBigImageContainer').find('img');
    flyToElement($(itemImg), $('.cart_anchor'));
   window.location.reload();
}

function flyToElement(flyer, flyingTo) {
    var $func = $(this);
    var divider = 3;
    var flyerClone = $(flyer).clone();
    $(flyerClone).css({position: 'absolute', top: $(flyer).offset().top + "px", left: $(flyer).offset().left + "px", opacity: 1, 'z-index': 1000});
    $('body').append($(flyerClone));
    var gotoX = $(flyingTo).offset().left + ($(flyingTo).width() / 2) - ($(flyer).width()/divider)/2;
    var gotoY = $(flyingTo).offset().top + ($(flyingTo).height() / 2) - ($(flyer).height()/divider)/2;

    $(flyerClone).animate({
        opacity: 0.4,
        left: gotoX,
        top: gotoY,
        width: $(flyer).width()/divider,
        height: $(flyer).height()/divider
    }, 700,
    function () {
        $(flyingTo).fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(flyingTo).fadeIn('fast', function () {
                $(flyerClone).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(flyerClone).remove();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but it did not work. I also tried to add a callback function in my animation function after Jay Blanchards suggested it in his comment, but that also did not work. I have added an answer with my solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figuered out how to get it to work by adding .promise().done(function(){
            window.location.reload();} at the end of the animation function. See code below. Still confused over why a callback function didn´t do the trick...
explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
function flyToElement(flyer, flyingTo) {
    var $func = $(this);
    var divider = 3;
    var flyerClone = $(flyer).clone();
    $(flyerClone).css({position: 'absolute', top: $(flyer).offset().top + "px", left: $(flyer).offset().left + "px", opacity: 1, 'z-index': 1000});
    $('body').append($(flyerClone));
    var gotoX = $(flyingTo).offset().left + ($(flyingTo).width() / 2) - ($(flyer).width()/divider)/2;
    var gotoY = $(flyingTo).offset().top + ($(flyingTo).height() / 2) - ($(flyer).height()/divider)/2;

    $(flyerClone).animate({
        opacity: 0.4,
        left: gotoX,
        top: gotoY,
        width: $(flyer).width()/divider,
        height: $(flyer).height()/divider
    }, 700,
    function () {
        $(flyingTo).fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(flyingTo).fadeIn('fast', function () {
                $(flyerClone).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(flyerClone).remove();
                });
            });
        });
    }).promise().done(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the following which I suppose is causing the problem:

```
function flyToCart(reload) {
$('html, body').animate({
    'scrollTop' : $(".cart_anchor").position().top
});

var itemImg = $('.productBigImageContainer').find('img');
flyToElement($(itemImg), $('.cart_anchor'));

reload();
}
```

**Steps that lead to your problem:**

1. The `success` callback of your AJAX call invokes the function `flyToCart()`.
2. The function performs the animation and reloads the page (*well in fact, both at the same time, not as you'd expect*).

**Your Expectation:**

The call to `reload()` function should only occur once the animation is over.

**The Actual Process:**

jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method behaves in a way similar to that of a *promise*.

A [**promise**](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) enables you to chain different actions, where each of those actions could depend on one or more other actions' state. The state can be either *resolved* or *rejected*.

Lets assume you have actions `A` and `B`. Action `B` depends on the state of action `A`. Therefore, action `B` is fired only when `A` has finished (*resolved*).

In the extract taken from your code, since the call to `reload()` function is not **bound** to whether the animation has finished (i.e. the call `reload()` is outside the scope of the animation's promise), you end up with the call to `reload()` being executed in parallel with the `animate()` method.

In other words, the execution of code coming right after your `animate` call does not depend on whether `animate()` has finished its execution.

**Workaround:**

As stated in the comments, you can either make use of the `complete` callback of the `animate()` method:

```
function flyToCart(reload) {
$('html, body').animate({
    'scrollTop' : $(".cart_anchor").position().top
}, 
function(){   // the callback that is executed once the animation is over
    var itemImg = $('.productBigImageContainer').find('img');
    flyToElement($(itemImg), $('.cart_anchor'));  // move reload() to the callback of the animate in this function
});
}

/** your flyToElement function */
function flyToElement(flyer, flyingTo) {
/* ... */
 $(flyerClone).animate({
    opacity: 0.4,
    left: gotoX,
    top: gotoY,
    width: $(flyer).width()/divider,
    height: $(flyer).height()/divider
}, 700, function(){
    /*...*/
    reload(); // call reload() here
});
```

OR, use the *promise* returned by the `animate()` method (as you've done already):

```
$(selector).animate({ /* ... */ }).promise().done(function(){
    //do some stuff when the promise is resolved.
});
```

That is:

```
$(flyerClone).animate({ /* ... */ }).promise().done(function(){
    reload();
});
```

**Note:** *You are in fact doing animations with `animate()` twice in your code. You need to move the `reload()` to the callback of your second `animate()` method so that you wait until all the animations are over.*